# Bootstrap - Have Row take up remaining height of container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I do not want my page to allow any overflow larger than the screen size. I will have a container that consists of two rows. (red and green bellow). I would like the top row (red) to resize based upon what is in it. I then would like the bottom row (green) to the automatically fill up the remaining space. I do not want it to expand outside of the initial container nor do i want it to scroll for the time being.

What classes/css/flexbox properties are required to do this?

[image]